# ConstraintViolationException on nullable Integer QueryParam with @Min

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using JAX-RS (Jersey implementation) with bean validation and have the following parameter as a field in my resource class:

```
@Min(1) @Max(100)
@QueryParam("imageQuality")
private int imageQuality = -1;
```

The idea behind this parameter is that it is not required in the request, but if it happens to be present in the request, its value should be between 1 and 100 (inclusive).

When I perform a simple GET (without this parameter), I get a `ConstraintViolationException` on this parameter, saying that the value `0` (the default value for an int) is invalid.

So it looks like some weird stuff is happening. Why isn't the value -1? Why do I get this exception if I don't specify the parameter?

Comment: If it's nullable, I would use Integer instead of int, and set it to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Min: null elements are considered valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html)

As @JB Nizet commented, you should do like this.

```
@QueryParam("imageQuality")
@Min(1)
@Max(100)
private Integer imageQuality;
```

If you want a default value,

```
@DefaultValue("50")
@QueryParam("imageQuality")
@Min(1)
@Max(100)
private int imageQuality;
```